# I'm building a telegram bot but I'm getting late data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, telegram-bot

I have an interface in a Telegram bot, I make it through Node.js and buttons, when you click on which you need to enter data.
I use mongoDB and store all user data in it. I have a PlusMinus value in it, which should help me find out what the user wants to do, take away from the balance or add.
There is also a button to change plus to minus, but when you click on this button, the old value is returned to me. That is, if there was a plus, I wanted to change it to a minus, I press the button - I get a plus again, and when I use it again, there will be a change to a minus. How can I fix this delay?

```
User.updateOne({telegramID: query.from.id}, {$set: {AssetPlusMinus: 'Minus'}})
                        .then(user1 => {
                            user1.save
                            bot.deleteMessage(chatID, msgID)
                        })
bot.sendPhoto(chatID, PhotoCrypto, {
        caption: textCrypto,
        reply_markup: {
            inline_keyboard: keyboard.AssetMenu(PlusOrMinus)
        }
    })
```

I tried many methods in which the function will be launched only after the execution of another function, but it did not help me

Clarification:
When you click on the change button, the old value is returned to me, but a new one is put in the database, that is, it changes but does not have time to be processed (As I understand it)

I'm new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the updated code which addresses the delay issue:

```
User.updateOne({ telegramID: query.from.id }, { $set: { AssetPlusMinus: 'Minus' } })
  .then(() => {
    return User.findOne({ telegramID: query.from.id }); // Fetch the updated user data
  })
  .then(user => {
    // Use the updated user data
    user.save();
    bot.deleteMessage(chatID, msgID);
    bot.sendPhoto(chatID, PhotoCrypto, {
      caption: textCrypto,
      reply_markup: {
        inline_keyboard: keyboard.AssetMenu(user.AssetPlusMinus)
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle any errors that occurred during the update or fetch operations
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Cheers!

Comment: Whoa! Thanks a lot! I don't quite understand what exactly has changed, but in general I understand!

Comment: No problem! I’ve added and changed some of your code such as a .then function, etc! If my code works, please mark it as an answer thanks again!

Comment: Yes, I already understood. You used return User.FindOne to get the already updated user when I was reading the old one. Thanks again!